2 Master & 1 Slave communication over RS485 Bus line
We are working on one of our projects where 2 Masters and 1 Slave are connected in the same RS485 bus lines, Now there is data collision is happening when both masters try to communicate with the same slave device.
Attached Block diagram for the same.
Now, Is there any solution to avoid the collision ?? how do I know the bus status of the RS485 bus line.?
do I need to implement/add any extra hardware circuits??
Appreciate your help.
Thanks.
Regards,
Shivam


What protocol are you using to coordinate communication / priority?

We don't even know from your block diagram the required details how any of the devices currently work and what protocol you need to use. But the masters must take turns that they don't send at the same time. As an example, have each master wait 2 seconds before they transmit again, and then make each master to wait 1 second after the other master has transmitted.

Whether you're using a protocol like Modbus-RTU or similar, master/slave communication goes like this:

Master sends a command
The bus is silent while slave executes the command
Slave sends a reply

The silent part in the middle is part of the transaction. During this part, the slave does not expect a transmission from another master. If it occurs, it may buffer it and reply later, or it may simply ignore it.
So if you want do do multimaster on such a bus, it's not simply about waiting for the line to be silent before transmitting: you need a way to distinguish a silent bus which means the slave is ready to receive a command, and a silent bus which means the slave is already processing a command. So both masters would need to listen and talk to to each other.
I see several options:

Token ring style: each master tells the other "your turn now".

Implicit token ring: each master promises to wait X seconds between messages. The other master listens, and when it sees a message it knows it can transmit immediately after without risk of collision.

Ethernet-like: if there is no reply from the slave, maybe there was a collision. Resend the command after a random interval, hoping the other master picks another random interval so there is no collision next time.

Man in the middle: one of the masters has a second RS485 port which acts as a slave to the other. It sends its own commands and forwards the other master's commands to the slave, taking care to avoid mixing them up.

Hardware assistance: using a device like this one between the two masters and the slave to arbitrate.



Multi-master communication channels are notoriously difficult to get right, due to bus contention (collisions). Take a look at what the old 10BASE-2 over coax had to implement, with the help of a transport layer in software, to mitigate contention and other related issues. Members on the bus had only one way to know if a recipient successfully received a packet, and that was to require a recipient to respond, a so-called "ACK". Even so, an ACK can be lost, so participants must resend a packet after some timeout period without an ACK. Packets must also carry a serial number, which helps a recipient to identify resent packets, and ignore them if necessary. Collisions were also identified by an absence of ACK, after which the protocol was to wait some random amount of time and resend, randomness which increased the probability that the two senders wouldn't collide again. Additionally, each transmitted packet contains a checksum that the recipient uses to validate received data, ignoring anything that didn't pass validation.
I'll hazard a guess that you don't want to implement a full TCP-IP-like stack.
You could implement a hardware-and-software protocol to wait until the channel is quiet and high-impedance, before attempting to transmit, but that's not trivial either, and you'll still get occasional collisions.
When there's only one master, much of that complexity is alleviated, because collisions aren't possible. Even over a half-duplex channel, unless one of the participants breaks the rules, collisions won't occur, since a slave must never take control of the bus unless it is responding to the master's request. Without any collisions, the only source of error is noise, but error detection and correction can be rudimentary (implemented by the UART itself) since an RS485 channel is designed to be robust and noise-tolerant. Maybe there's no need for checksums at all.
If you can provide the masters with their own communication channel, you could somehow arrange a mutex-like lock system, with which either master could acquire exclusive access to the main channel, safe in the knowledge that the other won't attempt to use it until the lock is released.
Alternatively, have one of the masters become a slave too. Nothing is preventing the real master from periodically polling the now-slave "pseudo-master" to see if it wants a message and response relayed to/from the slaves, acting as a kind of proxy. It's slower, of course, but that will resolve all collision issues.

10Base-T over coax does not exist - those are either 10Base2 or 10Base5. And Ethernet itself has no concept of ACK packets, that's way higher up at the IP layer stack for TCP. 10base5 and 10base2 can detect collisions, not only by seeing the bits being garbage, but the amplitude of the two transmissions adding up and the signal level on coax cable being twice or higher due to collisioning signals adding up. That's why it's called the CSMA/CD and the collosion detecting node has to send a jamming signal so everyone sees there is a collision.

@Justme That's all true, I'll tweak it, thanks

Also multiple masters on RS-485 bus is just fine. They don't have their RX and TX lines connected together, because there is a single half-duplex channel where everyone can transmit when they want to drive the bus and everyone listens if somebody transmits on the bus. Are you mixing up RS-485 with something else like RS-422?

@Justme yes I am
